# python docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found when opening Document

Tags: python, docx

I want to open a .docx file with function `Document()`. But it always returns:

`docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at '/home/chaomaer/PycharmProjects/demo/lab1/book1.docx'`

However, when I change the function to  `open()`, it works well.

I want to know "why?"

```
from docx import Document
import os
document = open('book1.docx')
# document = Document('book1.docx')
print document.read()
```

Comment: A .docx format is a collection of heavily interdependent XML files. I would recommend looking into a library such as https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: It seems strange. Some of the .docx file can be opend with the function Document(),but some of the .docx file can not . It still raise the error like this:docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'book1.docx'

Answer (score 3):

I know a simple solution
I work in a ubantu Os
when the docx raise the error, try copy the file that can not be opened in a new file within MS word. It works for me 
if someone knows the deep reason. I woud to be appreciate to you.

Comment: If the path directory of the `.docx` file are wrongly given than also raise the same error.

Comment: Indeed. But I am sure the path is rigth

Comment: I would like to know you that all I tried from my windows PC and gives the same error if the path is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @chaomaer Seeing the same problem you described here where some .docx files open fine and others get this error. Can you clarify your Ubuntu solution above? It sounds like you manually open the file in MS Word... do you have an automated solution in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

First install `pip install python-docx`
And then change the code following:

```
from docx import Document
import os
#document = open('book1.docx')
document = Document('book1.docx')
for p in document.paragraphs:
    print p.text
```

It works for me. Hope this will help.

**EDIT:**

You should create docx file with MS or other suitable editor. My advice - use google docs if you have account. Creating file with `touch` command in the terminal doesn't help.

Comment: It seems strange. Some of the .docx file can be opend with the function Document(),but some of the .docx file can not . It still raise the error like this:docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'book1.docx'

Comment: ok.It seems your package has not installed successfully. will you please tell me which python version you are using?? if you use python3.x than install the package `pip3 install python-docx`.

Comment: I use ther version python 2.7

Comment: ok it's sounds good. I have also done it on my pc with version python2.7.x. Have you execute from command line `pip install python-docx`? if you execute this command successfully than please check in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\` have a folder named `docx`. If all is okey than the above code will run successfully. Thank you.

Comment: all the conditions you have mentioned I have checked is correct. But the answer is it still not works well. The file is still can not be found.It is there something wrong with my file .but I can open the file with MS word .I am very confused now. Finally, I am very thankful to you.

Comment: Put the `book1.docx` and `somthing.py` file in the same directory. or do change `document = Document('pathlocation\\book1.docx')`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that if I create the Word document by right-clicking in Windows Explorer and selecting New > Word Document, I will forever get the PackageNotFoundError on that document. If, instead, I open Microsoft Word and create the document through there, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. Turned out that the word document I tried to open with docx was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I had the word document open at the same time - even if I wasn't doing anything to it, it still threw this error. Closing the word document solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Writing Word Documents**

The following instruction where found in the book "automatetheboringstuff".

- To create your own ***.docx*** file, call ***docx.Document()*** to return a new, blank Word Document object.
- The ***add_paragraph()*** document method adds a new paragraph of text to the document and returns a reference to the Paragraph object that was added.
- When you’re done adding text, pass a filename string to the ***save()*** document method to save the ***Document*** object to a file.
- This will create a file named ***helloworld.docx*** in the current working directory.

**Enter the following into the interactive shell:**

```
>>> import docx
>>> doc = docx.Document()
>>> doc.add_paragraph('Hello world!')
<docx.text.Paragraph object at 0x0000000003B56F60>
>>> doc.save('helloworld.docx')
```

Seems that many of us where creating document with name, as we called the open object function, where as the docx library creates an empty file without name when open object function is called. location and Name needs to be added while saving the document.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I was facing the same issue but not on all Docx files only a few files. then I printed the local path of each file and found out that whenever I hit the **PackageNotFoundError** issue. Most of the time these files are temp Docx files and can't be open/read even from Microsoft applications.

Below is my code:

```
def _RsDocx_(SearchString, Path):
flag = 0
index = 0
doc = docx.Document(Path)
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    index += 1
    if SearchString in para.text:
        flag = 1
        break
if flag != 0:
    print('String', SearchString, 'Found In Line: ', index, 'File Path: ', Path)
```

I already Imported Docx lib and calling this def from the main